# GLSurfaceview set position using VideoRendererGui class in webrtc?

Tags: android, webrtc, glsurfaceview

I am using a GLSurfaceView for showing remote user's video stream in a webrtc based Android application. I am using libjingle library for that. I have to control video scaling i.e. from fit to fill and vice versa. The scaling is controlled but as I am doing from fill to fit , the last frame rendered on the GLSurfaceView is not getting deleted. Please if anyone could help me with that. I have tried lot of solutions but they are not working.

Please don't provide any solutions using Canvas, because I have tried that but they are not working here.